# Visual Studio 2010 Extension Manager crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, extensibility, vsix

After installing a bunch of extensions to try out I restarted VS 2010 and it started crashing. Unfortunately, it consistently crashes when opening Tools | Extension Manager. Any ideas how to fix and avoid a complete uninstall/reinstall?

Event log has this: Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AggregateException Stack: at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

Comment: Sorry, can't validate any resolutions because I'm no longer with the company where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 11):

Try using safemode

```
> devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

This will start Visual Studio with all add-ins/extensions disabled.

Comment: This is really helpful. Had to edit a Silverlight project that kept crashing Resharper.

Answer (score 4):

Try renaming the folder that contains the extensions (and thus, temporarily, removing them).

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions
```

This will show if you have a VS2010 installation problem, or it is due to an extension (or the interaction of two extensions).

If it is VS2010, try an installer repair, if it is the extensions, restore, and remove half and repeat until isolated.